# How to redirect from an action called on ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I need to redirect to "Home" action from "Login" action. "Login" action is called on ajax. So what's happening is the "Login" action is redirecting to "Home" action. But, as "Login" action is called on ajax, so the ajax success callback is executing. Instead I want a direct redirect from Login action to Home action. Is there any way to achieve this in the "Login" action itself?

Is "redirecting from success callback" only way of redirecting? I have several conditions based on which I need to redirect to different views. so It would be great, if I can redirect from the action itself

Comment: Can you not redirect to 'Home ' in the ajax success callback?

Comment: You can use `window.location.href='/Home/Index';` but why not just use a normal submit and `RedirectToAction();` in the controller?

Comment: you can pass different conditions from action to ajax as json and check for those conditions in ajax success callback and then redirect whereever you want as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect to **Home action** from ajax success callback as shown :

```
window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Home","ControllerName")'
```

write above code inside ajax success callback.

**EDIT :-**

You can use `RedirectToAction()` when you perform normal form submit but here you are doing ajax call so you have try code as shown in this answer,if you want to test conditions before redirecting then send those conditions from action to ajax request as Json and check those conditions in ajax callback and then redirect to appropriate controller action.